# Call some jquery 3 seconds after .load()

Tags: jquery

I have this this jquery that loads a success message in a modal:

```
$('#menu_access').load(
    site_url + sUrl,
    function() {
        $(this).dolPopup(oPopupOptions);
    }
);
```

I want to call this function three seconds after the load:

```
$('#menu_access').dolPopupHide({});
```

I'm not sure how to go about it.  I'm not too familiar with the .load() function.

Comment: .load() is notoriously (and device-specifically) unreliable, ensure the entire DOM is loaded (thus so is your `#node´) instead: `$( function(){ /* your stuff here }`. — Many people tried .load() for images upon complete image-load (which is not covered by ‘DOM-loaded’, and you get a lot of pain, e.g. No load() event if already cached...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a call to `setTimeout(...)`

```
$('#menu_access').load(
    site_url + sUrl,
    function() {
        var menuAccess = $(this);
        menuAccess.dolPopup(oPopupOptions);
        setTimeout(function () {
            menuAccess.dolPopupHide({});
        }, 3000);
    }
);
```

Comment: hmm... not working for some reason.  This is being called from inside a function

Comment: `this` isn't the proper element inside the function passed to `setTimeout()` here.

Comment: @Nick You're right. I don't know how I missed that. I fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Then after this edit, It works perfect.  Thanks Everyone for the help.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [jQuery's `delay()` method](http://api.jquery.com/delay/), but you need to add your plugin call to the queue using [jQuery's `.queue()` method](http://api.jquery.com/queue/).

```
$('#menu_access').load(
    site_url + sUrl,
    function() {
        $(this).dolPopup(oPopupOptions);
        $(this).delay(3000)
               .queue( function( nxt ) {
                      $(this).dolPopupHide({});
                      nxt();
                });
    }
);
```

Note that the parameter to the function passed to `.queue()` needs to be called in order to allow the next animation to occur (at any time).

As an alternative, you can use `setTimeout()`, but you need to make sure the value of `this` is correct in the callback.

```
$('#menu_access').load(
    site_url + sUrl,
    function() {
        $(this).dolPopup(oPopupOptions);
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
                      $(that).dolPopupHide({});
                }, 3000);
    }
);
```

Here `this` is referenced by the variable `that`.

Or you could use [jQuery's `$.proxy()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) to ensure the proper meaning of `this`.

```
$('#menu_access').load(
    site_url + sUrl,
    function() {
        $(this).dolPopup(oPopupOptions);
        setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
                      $(this).dolPopupHide({});
                }, this), 3000);
    }
);
```

Comment: where do I add $(this).dolPopupHide({});?

Comment: @what - Sorry, I should have had that in where the `.dolPopup(oPopupOptions)` is. I'll correct.

Comment: +1 - Complete and correct, curious how the other answers got +3, one's inefficient and one's wrong....`setTimeout()` is *definitely* the way to go here.

Comment: @Nick - Agreed. I don't see any real benefit to `.delay(ms).queue(fn)`. Extra overhead, and the code isn't any simpler/shorter/more compatible.

Comment: Good Stuff.  I'm working inside of a large script that has alot of js problems.  It was the close function i was trying to use that was failing me.  So I just added some .remove() 's and setTimeout() works like a charm.

Comment: @what - Glad it worked. In my opinion, it would be much better to use some reference to `this` in the `setTimeout()` instead of selecting it again from the DOM using `"#menu_access"`. You have a direct reference to the element. Might as well use it. :o)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) function.